# Plugin: jQuery Kwicks - Gap on last panel bigger than others

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I feel like I've tried changing every value, attempted different margin settings, etc, but the last panel just won't budge. Link to page:

http://cpogallery.com/blog/photography-imaging/

I have no idea what the problem could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. More info below:

The script is within the Wordpress page rather than Header.php, that's the only way I could get it to even work. But the gap on the last panel, even if reduced to 4 panels for example, is always bigger than the others.

http:/cpogallery.com/blog/js/

**CSS**

## bglink {

display:block;
width: 120px;
height:500px;
padding: 0 0 0 9999px;

}
.kwicks {
/* recommended styles for kwicks ul container */
list-style: horizontal;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.kwicks li{
/* these are required, but the values are up to you (must be pixel) */
width: 120px;
height: 500px;

/*do not change these */
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
}
.kwicks.horizontal li {
margin-right: 0;
float: left;
}

## kwick_1 {

background-color: #4979f3;
}

## kwick_2 {

background-color: #8D41AB;
}

## kwick_3 {

background-color:  #d74545;
}

## kwick_4 {

background-color:#f1f368 ;
}

## kwick_5 {

background-color:#40a944 ;

}
.kwicks.horizontal #kwick_5 {
}

Answer (score 0):

On a quick view I can't pinpoint the exact reason why you are getting the gap, but is there a reason you can't simply use some css to fix the style? move it left a few pixels until it looks and feels right. e.g. `position:relative;left:-5px;`

Comment: It seems to be behaving funny if you do that. 'left:' makes it jump to the left side, on top of the blue panel, to make it behave like a left-aligned panel. And 'right:' makes it do what it should as you load the page, but then it just jumps right back to where it was.  I've kept it with 'right:' so you can see what I mean, if your browser behaves the same way mine do.